# In an Alexa skill lambda function, can I make a call to a shell script when a certain intent is invoked?

Tags: python, ssh, aws-lambda, remote-access, alexa-skills-kit

I have a remote postfix mail server that has some data I want to return for a user when they ask "read my information." For this intent, in my getResponse() function, I make a call to a function getInfo(), whose return value I will pass to the speech_output. Within this function, I want to use ssh to access the remote machine and collect the data.

Currently, I have a shell script in the same directory that can collect the data from the remote server, called retrieveInfo.sh that writes the data to a file call readingFile. I have written the following code inside my getInfo() function:

```
subprocess.call(['./retrieveInfo.sh'])
f=open("./readingFile", "r")
retVal = f.read()
return retVal
```

All of this code works, except for the subprocess call. However, when I run this code, including the subprocess call in another setting(not Alexa testing, just my own debugging), everything works fine. Does this have to do with packaging deployment? I have tried to upload a zip file with subprocess installed but that has not seemed to work either. I am not sure if this is an environmental issue, or some other problem?

It basically comes down to the following: When an intent is invoked, how can I make it run another program to collect some data for me? Or is there a way for me to access that remote machine through the lambda python function itself? I tried package deployment with paramiko, but that did not work either.

Comment: does your shell script need root rights? maybe try each line in your shell script using 
os.system(command)

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. Is there some other way for AWS lambda, when called from an Alexa Skill to pull data from a remote machine?